# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying func issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, fatal-error

I am trying to make my app so that when a user touches a UIImageView A certain sound will play. However, while that sound is playing, I want the UIImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled to be assigned to false. Once the sound is done playing I want the UIImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled to be assigned to true.  When ever I run the following code I get an error in the card class, even if I force unwrap. Below is the class that contains the image view I want to disable.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {
@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

 func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
   imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    itemList[imageIndex].playSound()

}
}
```

This is the class where the playSound func is located.

```
import Foundation; import UIKit; import AVFoundation

class Card: NSObject
{
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
var svc = SecondViewController()

var image: UIImage
var soundUrl: String

init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String, isActive:Bool = true) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl

}
func playSound()
{
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player?.delegate = self
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
        audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player)


        print("play")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}

extension Card: AVAudioPlayerDelegate  {
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer){
 svc.imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

this is the error I get 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var svc = SecondViewController()
```

That `svc` is not *your* SecondViewController, the existing one in the interface with an `imgPhoto`. Instead, you are creating a new, separate, and above all *blank* view controller with an empty view, so its `imgPhoto` is `nil` and you crash when you refer to it.

What you want to do is use the "delegate" pattern to hold a reference to the *real* SecondViewController so you can talk to it.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793064/swift-4-switch-page-view-controller-programatically and many many many others. This is a common mistake, caused by a failure to understand the difference between class and instance.